# What is the point of vectors who's components add to zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am doing a simple practice question:

Every combination of *v* = (1,-2,1) and *w* = (0,1,-1) has components that add to ____ . Find *c* and *d* so that *c***v** + *d***w** = (3,3,-6). Why is (3,3,6) impossible?

I know the blank is "zero" and c = 3, d = 9. The last part I didn't get --- (3,3,6) is impossible because it doesn't add up to zero.

What am I supposed to take away from this? Is there some property or definition here? (I'm starting linear algebra)

Comment: In short, yes. The set of all vectors whose components sum to $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^3$. There's a good chance you don't know what this means yet, but you will probably appreciate it more when you learn about bases, dimensions, vector spaces and subspaces of vector spaces.

Comment: While it is common to specify a subspace as being the span of some vectors, it is equally useful to specify that subspace as being the solution space to linear equations. The latter approach is what the given analysis is exploiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two linearly independent vectors $(1,-2,1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$ in the three dimensional space $\mathbb {R^3}$

Any linear combination of $(1,-2,1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$ is a vector whose components add up to $0$

The subspace spanned by these two vectors is  a two dimensional subspace which does not include vectors whose components do not add up to $0$.

Therefore $(3,3,6)$ is not in that subspace since it is not a linear combination of $(1,-2,1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$

Answer (score 1):

I would think of the problem this way: suppose you can move around $\mathbb{R}^3$ along the directions of the two vectors ${\bf v}=(1,-2,1)$ and ${\bf w}=(0,1,-1)$ (and let's say you start from the origin). Now, *where can you go*?

The point is that you can get from the origin to a point in this way if that point (or rather, the *position vector* of that point: the vector from the origin to the point) can be written in the form $c{\bf v}+d{\bf w}$ for some scalars $c$ and $d$ ("move $c$ units in the ${\bf v}$-direction and $d$ units in the ${\bf w}$-direction and you'll be there"). So this exercise is showing that you *can* get to $(3,3,-6)$ but you *can't* get to $(3,3,6)$.

Why this is a valuable question to ask, you'll learn later; for now, you're just exploring the way vectors let you move around the space (or, if you prefer, how vectors describe regions in the space) via **linear combinations**.

Comment: this answer really is a neat explanation

Answer (score 0):

The takeaway of this question is:

when the sum of components of v is 0, the sum of components of w is 0, then every combination of v and w has components that sum is zero.